# PHP PDO execute 2 queries in the event of a duplicate key

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am currently using this query

```
insert into races(race_city_id, race_date, racers, division, elimination)
values (:race_city_id, :race_date, :racers, :division, :elimination)
on duplicate key update
    race_city_id = values(race_city_id),
    race_date = values(race_date),
    racers = values(racers),
    division = values(division),
    elimination = values(elimination);
```

with a unique key on race_date, division, and elimination. I am currently using `on duplicate key`, but on a duplicate key found, I need to either delete and insert a new row into races (2 queries) or somehow regenerate the id field of the row and update some fields in it. I am using InnoDB and I have read that when you update a row the primary key would be regenerated, but mine is not. The id is set to auto increment, so I'm not sure if there is a way to regenerate the key.

The query updates the row properly, but I just need the key to be regenerated too.

Comment: You realize you're attaching the values on the insert with pdo, but not on the duplicate keys? `on duplicate key update
    race_city_id = values(:race_city_id), etc...`

Comment: @Xorifelse I'm pretty sure that using value(xxx) takes the value that would be inserted, and in this case it was from pdo. This is what I have used for 4 other queries that I have made. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_values

Comment: After doing a little research it seems you are correct, however the query does what it reads, it updates the values and leaves the id alone. Perhaps using `replace into races` would resolve your situation (obviously removing the `on duplicate key update` part)

Comment: @Xorifelse Well is there a way to make it regenerate the id? I guess I could find the max of every id, but then the auto increment feature would be off after that, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the query to:

```
replace into races(
  race_city_id, 
  race_date, 
  racers, 
  division, 
  elimination
) values (
  :race_city_id,
  :race_date,
  :racers,
  :division,
  :elimination
)
```

As `replace into` works exactly like `insert` except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a *primary key* or a *unique index*, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted, generating a new id.